# rtmp live AND RTMP FLV

Tags: rtmp, red5

how to interrupt rtmp flv broadcast and publish live rtmp broadcast on red5?
I am using osmf strobe player. I have my flv playlist working but when I broadcast live from my webcam what is the formula to stop the flv streams, then play flv countdown video then connect live broadcast from web cam?

Comment: What you've posted is semi-confusing. Do you want a playlist pre-roll, then a count down flv, then on to a live broadcast?

Comment: yes, I already gave playlist working, When I click to broadcast I want to trigger countdown video then I want live stream from my cam to go live. then when I stop broadcasting I want to make the playlist to resum

Comment: See my answer, you're gonna have add some signaling code to your app and clients.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it, from a high-level since I don't have the code for what you're asking and "easy" transitions between streams isn't built-in to the server.
First, create a signaling or event system within your app to accept actions triggered by your broadcaster. Using the signaling system, transition your subscribers / viewers by sending triggered events telling their players to stop playing a current video and start a new one. I suggest using Shared Objects for this when passing signals around. Use server-side methods called by your broadcaster to send the signals on the Share Object. The "play" functionality is the easy part since you simply provide the stream name in your signal / event.